# How do I strip leading section of this string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string:

```
[BN_D]hostName=localhost
```

How do I strip [BN_D] from the string using perl? This would give me the string:

```
hostName=localHost
```

Comment: Potential [`XY Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Stripping that prefix is easy. A better question would be to understand why `[BN_D]` is there in the first place.  If this is part of a large config file, it likely has a specific format that MIGHT already have a module intended to parse it.  That would be a much better solution if it was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

`^[^]]*.(.*)$`

for that

Answer (score 2):

I would use this regex `^\[\w+\]` since `\w+` matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

```
 ...
my $str = "[BN_D]hostName=localhost";
$str =~ s|^\[\w+\]||;
print $str;
 ...
```

**output**

```
hostName=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `[...]` part with nothing:

```
'[BN_D]hostName=localhost' =~ s/\[.*?\]//r
```